# Cannot attach project in DataSpell

Tags: github, dataspell

On the welcome screen of DataSpell I chose to open a project with **Get from Version Control** to get a project from GitHub, although in the left pane I didn't choose GitHub, so it created an empty **.git** repository.

After that, I git cloned elsewhere the git repository or tried to clone it correctly from GitHub but in every occasion I get

```
Error
Cannot attach project Module name 'project name' already exists. 
Trying to load module: /path/to/project name.iml
```

Where does DataSpell save the imported projects, to detach the empty project that I imported initially?

Comment: I've the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to open the project following the instructions of [Open your project from disk](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/dataspell/creating-and-managing-projects.html#open-local-project) section of the DataSpell site.

For avoiding further trouble, I opened the project in a new window. After the configuration in step 2 **Reopen projects on startup** --> **Ask**, Dataspell will ask how to open the project.

Answer (score 3):

This has been happening to me more frequently in DataSpell 2022.3 on my M1 Apple machines.  To solve the issue, I did the following:

- `Settings > Project: [Project Name] > Project Structure`.
- Click `+ Add Content Root` and select the root folder of your project.
- Press `Apply` or `OK`

You ***should*** now see your project folder in the Files section of the Workspace.

Answer (score 2):

**File --> Invalidate caches... --> INVALIDATE AND RESTART** worked for me (with no options selected for the final step).

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked

```
File > Manage IDE Settings > Restore Default Settings...
```